# How to completely fill a div without a set height with an image

Tags: html, css, jsx

I have this JSX

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
  <div className='outer-div'>
    <div className='first-div'>
      a <br />
      b <br />c
    </div>
    <div className='second-div'>
      <img
        src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Eiffel_Tower_Vertical.JPG'
        alt=''
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className='outer-div'>
    <div className='first-div'>
      a <br />
      b <br />c
    </div>
    <div className='second-div'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
.outer-div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.first-div {
  background-color: red;
}

.second-div {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.second-div > img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I wanted the image to fit the div completely, but instead it is like this:

[image]

I noticed that if the screen is thinner, the problem doesn't happen, like here:

[image]

How can I make it so the image completely fills the `second-div` for any screen size, without having a set height?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the image relative to the div.

```
.second-div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.second-div > img {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: add `overflow: hidden;` to `.second-div` like this

```
.second-div {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It works, but I'm not sure why. Would appreciate if anyone could explain it.